# Combining many boxplots into fewer boxplots in R using boxplot(x~y)

Tags: r, boxplot

I am very new to R and I am currently trying to take a scatter plot of thousands of points spread over a range of 1000 and make just a few boxplots with key information. I want to make boxplots of those points but when I do:
Boxplot(x~y) I get so many plots that the image is black. I want to combine the boxes such that for every step of 50 from 0 to 1000 the program creates a new boxplot. Thus I want 20 boxplots or so instead of 1000 of them or however many there are.

Thank you for the help in advance

Comment: And what have you tried already? Did you check in with any documentation available out there, like [this very first one](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/boxplot.html)?